# how can this algorithm be optimized

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20 and here is the code:

```
$num = 2520;
$x = 1;

while($x < 21){
    if($num % $x == 0){
        $x++;
    }else{
        $num += 20;
        $x = 1;
    }
}

echo $num;
```

it gives a proper output in less than 1 minute. Is this execution time bad in the professional world? any way to optimize this?

P.S. I started from 2520 because it is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

Comment: [Least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Computing_the_least_common_multiple)

Comment: You don't need a program for this, it's 2^4*3^2*5*7*11*13*17*19. It's the product of all primes raised to as large a power as possible without going over 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use modified Sieve of Eratosthenes for massive speed up

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
- but do not use array instead iterate just indexes
- something like

1.int ix[20]={1,2,3,4,...20};

2.now write a loop

- where you will increment all ix[i]+=i+1; where i=<0;18>
- while ix[i]>=ix[19]
- if at the end all ix[i] are the same then its contens is the result so stop/return whatever

3.if not then increment also ix[19]+=20;

- and continue with the loop on bullet 2

[notes]

- can be easily changed for searing for divisible by any numbers not just divisible by 1..20

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:  find the primes of all integers in [1,20].

Eg, we have the primes {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}.  So, if the solution is divisible
by all integers in [1,20], then surely it is divisible by each element in this
list of primes.  So, at a minimum, our solution is >= 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19, right?

Now the problem is how clever we can be about constructing candidate solutions
larger than that number.  Well, let's first see how much of the solution is done...

Is 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19 divisible by 4?  No.  So, let's multiple by 2 to get
2*2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19, which surely is divisible by 2*2...

Is 2*2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19 divisible by 6?  Yes.

Is 2*2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19 divisible by 8?  ....

You get the picture.  While I am not sure, I believe this approach will
result in the right answer -- ie, the smallest integer divisible by each
integer in [1,20].

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [Project Euler's Problem 5](http://projecteuler.net/problem=5).

What we are finding here is the [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of numbers 1 to 20. You can find this with help form the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor):

```
function gcd($a, $b) {
    if ($a == 0) return $b;
    return gcd($b % $a, $a);
}

function lcm($a, $b) {
    return $a * $b / gcd($a, $b);
}

function smallestDiv($n) {
    $div = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $div = lcm($div, $i);
    }
    return $div;
}

echo smallestDiv(20);
```

Pardon my PHP. It's been a while since I have written any.

Note that we can also find the answer via prime factorization of each of the numbers and looking for the largest exponents as described [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastCommonMultiple.html) and in [Kode Charlie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1378268/kode-charlie) answer:

```
 2 = 2
 3 = 3
 4 = 2²
 5 = 5
 6 = 2 × 3
 7 = 7
 8 = 2³
 9 = 3²
10 = 2 × 5
11 = 11
12 = 2² × 3
13 = 13
14 = 2 × 7
15 = 3 × 5
16 = 2⁴
17 = 17
18 = 2 × 3²
19 = 19
20 = 2² × 5

lcm(1,2,…20) = 2⁴ × 3² × 5 × 7 × 11 × 13 × 17 × 19 = 232,792,560
```